# How to delete specific number of nodes from firebase realtime database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have an app which has a structure like

Chatrooms--------
Messages-------
Chatroomid---------
-Message1
-Message2

In this chatroom when the number of messages reaches 200 I want to delete the first 50 messages.So if the messages are 200 it will delete the messages from message1 to message50.I am using a push key for the messages.

**My java code for sending message**

```
send.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {

              Map<String,Object> message = new HashMap<>();
              message.put("message",messageBox.getText().toString());
              message.put("imageurl",ppurl);
              message.put("sender",FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

              reference2.push().setValue(message).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                  @Override
                  public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {

                      messageBox.setText("");

                  }
              }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {

                      Toast.makeText(chatroom.this, "Error" + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                  }
              });

          }
      });
```

**My java code for retrieving message**

```
    private void getdata() {
        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        message l = npsnapshot.getValue(message.class);
                        list.add(l);
                    }

                    messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }else {


                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can easily add this in your existing `getdata` function:

```
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.exists()) {
            if (snapshot.getChildrenCount() > 200) {
                int count = 0;
                Map<String, Object> updates = new HashMap<>();
                for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (count++ <= 50) {
                        updates.put(npsnapshot.getKey(), null);
                    }
                }
                ref.updateChildren(updates); // this will refire onDataChange, so we'll update the UI then                
            }
            else {
                for (DataSnapshot npsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
                    message l = npsnapshot.getValue(message.class);
                    list.add(l);
                }

                messageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
        throw error.toException(); // don't ignore errors
    }
});
```

There is also a Cloud Functions sample that can do this server-side for you btw: https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/limit-children